# Sorting and matching values in two columns in an Excel sheet and between two excel sheets

Tags: excel, sorting, match

I am new to EXCEL and I am working on a work related project where I am trying to compare the data in two columns that have almost the same data but with a few things missing(one column may have a subset of the other column) or wrong capitalization etc...; but most likely sorted similarly. So, the way I want this to be done is, I want to check the data in Column B and Column A against one another and if the values in the adjacent cells match (A4 = B4) then just leave it as is and, if the data does not match then A blank cell needs to be only added to one column (Example: inserting a blank cell to Column B) and check the same data from one column with the next cell value. I have attached a sample of this that I have just put together to help you understand what I am trying to do.

[Just example data before sorting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Iiz.png)

[Example after sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsAFJ.png)

Thank you in advance.

Since I am new to Excel I tried understanding MATCH, INDEX and loops(VBA) but I ended up more confused that before.

Comment: formula won't be able to rearrange cells, macro may be, but it is unnecessary for this task. may I know the purpose of sorting the two columns this way? Maybe there is an easier to achieve what you need to do.

Comment: Pls. don't post data as picture. Use [markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/), or at least insert data as code format. It is much more easier to reproduce it for investigation.